# using user generated variables in imported functions python

Tags: python, function, python-import

I'm not sure what to call this so I'll just explain what I need to do

Say I have the following script that gets a user inputs:

```
#test0.py

import functions

number = input('pick a number')
functions.dothis()
```

and this:

```
#functions.py
def dothis(): 
    global number
    if number == 1:
        print('the number is 1')
    else: 
        print('the number is not one')
```

this obviously shoots out `'number' is not defined`.

How do I pass `number` into the `dothis()` function or am I going about this entirely the wrong way ?

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it as an argument, like so:

```
def dothis(number): 
    if number == 1:
       ...

number = input('pick a number')
functions.dothis(number)
```

Comment: yep, works a treat, thanks